# XPath that excludes some part of selected element?

Tags: xml, xpath

XML:

```
    <root>
      <rows>
        <row hash="156458">
          <column name="Id">1</column>
          <column name="Nome">Evandro</column>
          <column name="CPF">98765432100</column>
        </row>
        <row hash="52458">
          <column name="Id">2</column>
          <column name="Nome">Everton</column>
          <column name="CPF">12345678900</column>
        </row>
      </rows>
    </root>
```

XPath query:

`./root/rows/row/column[@name='Nome'] | ./root/rows/row/column[@name='CPF']`

XPath return:

```
    <root>
      <column name="Nome">Evandro</column>
      <column name="CPF">98765432100</column>
      <column name="Nome">Everton</column>
      <column name="CPF">12345678900</column>
    </root>
```

What I wish the XPath return:

```
    <root>
      <rows>
        <row hash="156458">
          <column name="Nome">Evandro</column>
          <column name="CPF">98765432100</column>
        </row>
        <row hash="52458">
          <column name="Nome">Everton</column>
          <column name="CPF">12345678900</column>
        </row>
      </rows>
    </root>
```

I want to make the xpath preserve the document structure when I make the query.

Comment: The 'document structure' is maintained in the object model you are working with. So asking your columns.parent will actually return the 'row' object. Don't be fooled by the "serialized output of the DOM you're working with' when looking in a debugger/output

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. *Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results*. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: You're expecting too much from XPath.  Use XSLT here instead.

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes! This is the way. I just needed someone to tell me this.

Comment: And, I'm sorry if I seemed precipitated, but I don't come here and asked for help without lookup before. This seems not a popular subject on the forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath's great for selecting but not for structuring.  Step up to full XSLT for both.  A simple identity-based transformation is all you need...

**Given this XML input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <rows>
    <row hash="156458">
      <column name="Id">1</column>
      <column name="Nome">Evandro</column>
      <column name="CPF">98765432100</column>
    </row>
    <row hash="52458">
      <column name="Id">2</column>
      <column name="Nome">Everton</column>
      <column name="CPF">12345678900</column>
    </row>
  </rows>
</root>
```

**This XSLT transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="column[@name='Id']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce the desired XML output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <rows>
      <row hash="156458">
         <column name="Nome">Evandro</column>
         <column name="CPF">98765432100</column>
      </row>
      <row hash="52458">
         <column name="Nome">Everton</column>
         <column name="CPF">12345678900</column>
      </row>
   </rows>
</root>
```

**Notes:**

- The first template is the identify template; it will copy nodes from
  input to output unless a more specific template overrides it.
- The second template is an override to omit `Id` `column`s.